# How to left align the OutlineButton icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, alignment, flutter-layout

How to left align the `OutlineButton` icon in Flutter?
`Icon` can be added as follows, but both icon and text are centered aligned in the button. Is there a way to align the icon to the left and text to the center?

```
return new OutlineButton.icon(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  label: new Text(title),
  icon: icon,
  highlightedBorderColor: Colors.orange,
  color: Colors.green,
  borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)));
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are many ways you can do it, but it's not possible using the factory constructor that you mentioned `OutlinedButton.icon`, you can go deeper and check the source code to see how it build the widget.

You can create your own `Widget` to put an icon to the left and the text centered.

Also you can use the `OutlinedButton` widget and pass a Stack/Row as a child, check this sample

```dart
    OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () => null,
        child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm)
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                        "Testing",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )
                )
            ],
        ),
        highlightedBorderColor: Colors.orange,
        color: Colors.green,
        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Typo. It's `OutlinedButton`. There's a `d` before the B

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use `OutlinedButton.icon`, and simply wrap your Text with in `Center` like this:

```
return new OutlinedButton.icon(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  label: Center(child: new Text(title)),
  icon: icon,
)
```

If you want the text left-aligned, this also works:

```
return new OutlinedButton.icon(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  label: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: new Text(title)),
  icon: icon,
)
```

Comment: Clearly you did not read the original question. OP wants to align the icon, *not* the label text.

Comment: @KhoPhi Clearly, I did read the original question: "How to left align the OutlineButton icon in Flutter?" OutlineButton.icon aligns the *icon*. You can align the text *separately*.

Comment: This is a very sweet and simple answer. But can you help me understand why wrapping it in Center would do the trick? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Wrap Text Widget with Expanded widget.

```
         OutlinedButton.icon(

                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.lock,
                        color: MyAppTheme.accentColor,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                      label: Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          '      Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: MyAppTheme.primaryColor,
                              fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                          side: BorderSide(color: MyAppTheme.primaryColor)
                      ),
                     
                    ),
```

Comment: This throws the exception: `Expanded(flex: 1) (typically placed directly inside a Flex widget)`